# How to get the sum of a current column with a previous column in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a query that gets quantity 1, value 1 , total 1 what I am trying to get is the following result

```
quantity 1, value 1, total 1, sum quantity,  sum total / sum quantity as value summ, sum total
80 - 3.8 - 304 , 80 - 3.8 - 304
40 - 3.75 - 150, 120 - 3.783 - 454
40 -  3.8 -  152, 160 - 37875 - 606
```

that is to say, to be able to obtain the sum of the total, (total 1 + previous total sum)
to then do the division with quantity 1

I have tried using

```
SELECT 
@prev:= @prev + total 1 as column1,  @prev / quantity 1   as value
from table;
```

but I don't get the expected results

use MySQL 5.6 and windows S.O

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.x? Then you can use the `LAG()` window function to combine with the previous row.

Answer (score 0):

you can use user-defined variables to achieve the desired result. Here's an example query that calculates the cumulative sum and division:

```
SET @prev := 0;
SELECT
  quantity,
  value,
  total,
  @prev := @prev + total AS cumulative_total,
  (@prev / quantity) AS value_summ,
  @prev AS sum_total
FROM
  table_name;
```

Make sure to replace table_name with the actual name of your table.

This query initializes the `@prev` variable to `0`. Then, it selects the columns quantity, value, and total, and performs calculations using the user-defined variable `@prev` to calculate the cumulative total and the division. The results are displayed in the columns: quantity, value, total, cumulative_total, value_summ, and sum_total.

Note that user-defined variables are session-specific, so the @prev variable will retain its value within the same session. If you run this query multiple times in the same session, make sure to reset the variable by executing SET @prev := 0; again before running the query.

Comment: I have tried that and it gives me wrong values,

Comment: @DarkFenix how about this?
```
SET @prev := 0;
SELECT
  quantity,
  value,
  total,
  (@prev := @prev + total) AS cumulative_total,
  (@prev / quantity) AS value_summ,
  @prev AS sum_total
FROM
  table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using an `order by` clause, the results of your `@prev` value would be indeterministic. You need to have a column (id, timestamp...) that uniquely identifies the order of your rows, so the SQL can determine correctly what the previous value is.

consider the following example based on your sample data:

```
set @sum_quantity =0;
set @sum_total =0;
set @prev_tot_sum =0;

select *,
  @sum_quantity := @sum_quantity + quantity1 as sum_quantity,
  @sum_total := @sum_total + total1 as sum_total,
  @sum_total / @sum_quantity as 'sum total / sum quantity',
  @sum_total / quantity1 as 'value'
from table_name
order by id
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/OIKRiiY6)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 5.6 and want your answer in one single query

```
SELECT 
id, 
quantity1,
value1,
@sum_quantity:=@sum_quantity+quantity1 AS sumQuantity,
@sum_total:=@sum_total+total1 AS sumTotal,
@sum_total/@sum_quantity AS sumTotalBySumQuantity,
@sum_total/quantity1 AS val
FROM 
(SELECT 
  *,
  @sum_quantity:=0,
  @sum_total:=0, 
  @prev_tot_sum:=0
FROM
  table_name t ) a
```

This should work